# How do I append onto pipes?

Tags: bash, pipe

So my question is if I can somehow send data to my program and then send the same data AND its result to another program without having to create a temporary file (in my case ouputdata.txt).
Preferably using linux pipes/bash.

I currently do the following:

cat inputdata.txt | ./MyProg > outputdata.txt

cat inputdata.txt outputdata.txt | ./MyProg2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Choice 1 - fix `MyProg` to write the merged output from the input and it's own output.  Then you can do this.

```
./MyProg <inputdata.txt | ./MyProg2
```

Choice 2 - If you can't fix `MyProg` to write both input and output, you need to merge.

```
./MyProg <inputdata.txt | cat inputdata.txt - | ./MyProg2
```

Comment: Sorry but this solution is ugly. Just fix MyProg and chain them together with pipes.

Comment: a) this isn't ugly at all, b) the first choice proposes exactly that.

Answer (score 23):

Here is another way, which can be extended to put the output of two programs together:

```
( Prog1; Prog2; Prog3; ...  ) | ProgN
```

That at least works in Bash.

Comment: let's mix it together to get a fine meal: ( Prog1 & Prog2 & Prog3 & ...  ) | ProgN  :p

Comment: LOL, yeah, that'll give interesting results :-D